# Error StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while running program substring

Tags: java, substring, rgb, pixel

I would like to analyze the pixel value inside images. I try to take out value at the position 2 and 4 of hexadecimal pixel values and display it on the console. I'm using substring in my code. I try running the program but after a while, it displayed error stringoutofboundexception.

Error displayed:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at getPixelData.getPixelData(getPixelData.java:51)
at getPixelRGB.main(getPixelRGB.java:58)
```

These are my code:

```
public class getPixelData 
{
private static final double bitPerColor = 4.0;

public getPixelData()
{

}

public int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int w, int h) throws IOException
{
    int argb = img.getRGB(w, h);
    int rgb[] = new int[]
    {
        (argb >> 16) & 0xff, //red
        (argb >>  8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb      ) & 0xff  //blue
    };

    int red = rgb[0];
    int green = rgb[1]; //RGB Value in Decimal
    int blue = rgb[2];

    System.out.println("\nRGBValue in Decimal --> " + "\nRed: " + red + " Green: " + green + " Blue: " + blue);

    //Convert each channel RGB to Hexadecimal value
    String rHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(red));
    String gHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(green));
    String bHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(blue));

    System.out.println("\nRGBValue in Hexa --> " + "\nRed Green Blue " + rHex + gHex + bHex);

    //Check position 2 and 4 of hexa value for any changes
    String hexa2, hexa4 = "";
    String rgbHexa = rHex + gHex + bHex;

    hexa2 = rgbHexa.substring(1,2);
    System.out.println("\nString RGB Hexa: " + rgbHexa);
    System.out.println("\nSubstring at position 2: " + hexa2);

    //the program stops at here and then displayed the stringoutofboundexception
    hexa4 = rgbHexa.substring(3,4);
    System.out.println("\nSubstring at position 4: " + hexa4);

    ...

    return rgb;
}
}
```

Hoping for anyone to help me to solve my problem. I'm still new to Java.

Thanks

Comment: The hex string is not long enough. My guess would be that instead of "0A0B0C" it looks like "ABC" (i.e. no leading zeros).

Comment: What are you `rgb` values, and how does the generated string look, when you print it? Also, the bounds of your `substring` calls look odd. Which parts do you want to capture?

Comment: as an example, from rgb decimal value, 139 (red) 117 (green) 94 (blue) convert it to hexa value would be like this; 8B755E. I would like to take out value B from position 2 and value 5 from position 4. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method, the first index is inclusive, and the second index is exclusive. Also, note that counting starts with `0`, so to get `GG` from `RRGGBB` you have to call `substring(2, 4)`.

But you also have to make sure that the hex-strings have a leading zero. I.e., when you convert `15` to hex, the result is not `0F` but just `F`, making your string shorter than intended. You might want to use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead for [formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) the hex string.

```
int red = 139, green = 117, blue = 94;
String hex = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue);
String g = hex.substring(2, 4);
```

Comment: THANK YOUUU THANK YOUU SO MUCH! now it works! :D sorry for the late reply.